Tap doesn't trigger after debounceTime when using fakeAsync in jest/angular test
I'm trying to test this flow:
Angular component:
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    loading = true;

    data$?: Observable<string>;

    readonly control = new FormControl<string>('DATA', {nonNullable: true})
    readonly DEBOUNCE_MS = 500;

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.data$ = this.control.valueChanges.pipe(
            startWith(this.control.value),
            tap((x) => {
                this.loading = true;
            }),
            debounceTime(this.DEBOUNCE_MS),
            tap((x) => {
                this.loading = false;
            }),
        );
    }
}

Template:
@let data = data$ | async ;

@if (!loading) {
    <div data-testing-id="data">{{ data }}</div>
}

Test:
    it(`with fake async`, fakeAsync(() => { // This will fail
        fixture.detectChanges();
        tick(component.DEBOUNCE_MS + 10);
        fixture.detectChanges();

        expect(pageObject.data).toBeTruthy();
    }));

    it(`with fake async and whenStable`, fakeAsync(() => { // This works
        fixture.detectChanges();

        expect(component.loading).toEqual(true);

        fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
            expect(component.loading).toEqual(false);
            expect(pageObject.data.nativeElement.textContent).toEqual('DATA');
        });
    }));

    it(`with real async`, async () => { // This works too
        fixture.detectChanges();

        await realDelay(component.DEBOUNCE_MS);
        fixture.detectChanges();

        expect(pageObject.data).toBeTruthy();
    });

If I remove debounceTime everythins works, of course. Otherwise I can't reach second tap while debugging and test conditions are always falsy.
UPDATE:
I've updated the code according to @naren-murali answer and also created stackblitz example. I thought fakeAsync and timer are intended to solve issues like that, but they don't. We also can simulate real timer by awaiting Promise, but it seems to be "crutch" solution.
I would appreciate if anyone can explain why tick is not enough to handle this.

We can use autoDetectChanges() when testing async pipe.
beforeEach(() => {
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(App);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
  componentDe = fixture.debugElement;
  fixture.autoDetectChanges(); // <- important
});

We can use fixture.whenStable to wait for the DOM changes to be completed. Then inside the callback place our testing code.
Note that I am calling component.ngOnInit() manually so that the code is executed inside the test case only.
it('test', fakeAsync(() => {
  component.ngOnInit();
  expect(component.loading).toBeTruthy();
  fixture.detectChanges();

  fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
    expect(component.loading).toBeFalsy(); // this is still true
    expect(
      fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('[data-testing-id="test"]'))
        .nativeElement.textContent
    ).toContain('qwerty');
  });
}));

Full Code:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';
import { MyInputComponent } from './my-input-component/my-input.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AsyncPipe } from '@angular/common';
import {
  Observable,
  Subject,
  startWith,
  tap,
  debounceTime,
  switchMap,
  of,
} from 'rxjs';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [AsyncPipe, FormsModule],
  template: `
        @let test = test$ | async;

        @if (!loading) {
          <div data-testing-id="test">{{ test }}</div>
        }
      `,
})
export class App {
  test$?: Observable<string>;
  loading = false;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loading = true;
    this.test$ = new Subject<string>().pipe(
      startWith('1'),
      debounceTime(500),
      // here can be request like
      switchMap((value) => {
        return of('qwerty');
      }),
      tap(() => {
        this.loading = false; // this won't get triggered in test
      })
    );
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

testing:
import {
  ComponentFixture,
  fakeAsync,
  TestBed,
  flush,
  tick,
  flushMicrotasks,
} from '@angular/core/testing';

import { MyInputComponent } from './my-input.component';
import { Component, DebugElement } from '@angular/core';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { App } from '../main';

describe('MyInputComponent', () => {
  let component: App;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<App>;
  let componentDe: DebugElement;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [App],
    });
  });

    beforeEach(() => {
      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(App);
      component = fixture.componentInstance;
      componentDe = fixture.debugElement;
      fixture.detectChanges(); // <- important
    });

    it('test', fakeAsync(() => {
      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(App);
      component = fixture.componentInstance;
      componentDe = fixture.debugElement;
      fixture.autoDetectChanges(); // <- important
      component.ngOnInit();
      expect(component.loading).toBeTruthy();
      fixture.detectChanges();

      fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
        expect(component.loading).toBeFalsy(); // this is still true
        expect(
          fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('[data-testing-id="test"]'))
            .nativeElement.textContent
        ).toContain('qwerty');
      });
    }));
});

If you do not like calling ngOnInit inside the test case, you can change your code as below.
beforeEach(() => {
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(App);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
  componentDe = fixture.debugElement;
  fixture.detectChanges(); // <- important
});

it('test', fakeAsync(() => {
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(App);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
  componentDe = fixture.debugElement;
  fixture.autoDetectChanges(); // <- important
  component.ngOnInit();
  expect(component.loading).toBeTruthy();
  fixture.detectChanges();

  fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
    expect(component.loading).toBeFalsy(); // this is still true
    expect(
      fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('[data-testing-id="test"]'))
        .nativeElement.textContent
    ).toContain('qwerty');
  });
}));

Stackblitz Demo

@simple2k updated my answer with working example

Thanks for you answer! I've never used fixture.whenStable() before. It seems like your example can be simplified with just fixture.detectChanges(); and then doing expect inside fixture.whenStable().then(() => ... ). But I'm still wondering why tick method can't solve this issue, because it is intended to do so.

@simple2k the loading flag works, but the html part is having problem, I could be a bug with async pipe but raising a GitHub issue is best to understand what's wrong
